# OpenCV using monochromatic camera when throw frame to the output got 3 pictures instead of 1

Tags: python, opencv

I get frame from video using monochromatic camera oCam-1MGN-U . When I want throw frame to the output I got 3 pictures instead of 1. I know that this camera using 1 channel. How can I resolve this problem?

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
   cap = cv2.VideoCapture(1)    # Streamming from camera monochromatic
    while(cap.isOpened()):
        succes, frame = cap.read()
        if(succes):
            cv2.imshow('Orginal',frame)
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break

    cap.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
    print('End')
```

Im working on linux and I got three picture very similiar to this:

https://github.com/TheImagingSource/tiscamera/issues/20

Frame what I've got has shape: 480, 640, 3

What I tried:

- I've tested on OpenCV 3.2 and 3.4
- Get this frame and split it  `b, g ,r = cv2.split(frame)`  and throw
  only one channel to the output but still I get 3 pictures
- Change resolution of video streamming

Comment: Please provide [MCVE] reproducing this problem. An image illustrating the (incorrect) output would also help. (And just out of curiosity, what camera?)

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like this is an issue known since 2014:
https://github.com/TheImagingSource/tiscamera/issues/20

> The OpenCV capture class is in a very sad state (not only concerning v4l2). The reason your image looks that way is that it interprets the incoming Y800 as rgb while trying to maintain the correct resolution.
>   This can only be fixed by either patching OpenCV or by using other means to grab images.

Suggestion for monochromatic is to use:

```
cv2.imdecode(frame, CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE)
```

could you try and let us know if it works?

Comment: could you add more code? I don't have monochromatic camera next to me, but I could try to spot the issue?
I assume that you don't try to split your frame!

Comment: @trieser Then you will have to provide enough information (code, sample input) for us to replicate your problem. Simply saying "it doesn't work" doesn't give us anything to go on.

Comment: I added example code when I got three picture instead of one